# И снова о 33 богатырях

Tags: литература

Я тут уже задавала вопросы по поводу пушкинских 33 богатырей. Но вот мне всегда было интересно, а откуда вообще пошла такая легенда? Мне не верится, что это просто плод фантазии Пушкина. Наверняка он опирался на какие-то народные поверья и легенды. Но что это за 33 богатыря и зачем они то и дело выходят на берег?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Тоже всегда было интересно. А сколько во времена Пушкина было букв в алфавите? Богатырей-то 33, а с Черномором выходит 34.

Comment: В алфавите после правки Пётра оставалось 32 буквы. Зато некая парочка жила у моря тридцать лет и три года.

Answer (score 0):

33-священное число многих духовных традиций.

http://changing-world2020.blogspot.com/2012/01/33.html

В связи с образом 33 богатырей из сказки «О Царе Салтане»  имеет смысл вспомнить, что в ведийской мифологии, как и в древнеиранской (Видевдат), общее число древнейших богов составило 33: «Богов на небе – 11, на земле – 11, в водах – 11». Они и хранят чудный остров, а живут в глубинах океана Вечности. Таким образом, 33 богатыря – это воинство богов. Черномор соответствует славянскому Перуну или ведическому Индре.А.С.Пушкин хорошо ориентировался в ведической космологии и народных обрядовых текстах и умел находить среди них те, которые наиболее точно выражали его мысль. Я.Пропп, исследователь творчества Пушкина, утверждает, что русским крестьянам – современникам А.С. Пушкина не нужно было объяснять, что «остров Буян» – мир умерших, тот свет. Об этом говорило не только название чудесного острова, но и то, что «все в том острове богаты, изоб нет, везде палаты». 
Из этого же ряда и образы корабельщиков-гостей, которые плавают из царства Салтана к острову Буяну и обратно. В принципе, между ними и  «странниками», «чужаками» святочного ряженья можно поставить знак равенства, они также соединяют мир живых (царство Салтана) и 
мир мертвых (остров Буян).

Остров Буян  является «тем светом», местом, где обитают умершие, об этом свидетельствует и постоянное оборотничество князя Гвидона, который для всех своих возвращений в мир живых (царство Салтана) использует чужое обличье. Общеизвестно, что в народных представлениях у мертвых нет обычного земного тела («у навей нет облика»), поэтому они могут прийти в этот мир, только позаимствовав у кого-то его плоть. С этими представлениями связана традиция ряжения в Святки и на Масленицу – дни, посвященные предкам, возвращающимся в мир живых. Такое восприятие ряженых дошло практически до наших дней. Согласно данным, полученным фольклорно-этнографическими экспедициями под руководством А.М. Мехнецова, в 80-е – 90-е годы XX века во всех районах Псковской области старые люди  помнят о таких обязательных персонажах ряжения, как «предки» (старцы, покойники), «нелюди», «чужаки» (нищие, побирушки), «высокие старухи». По окончании  обрядовых циклов все возвращалось на свои места, и живые начинали жить по законам мира живых людей. Оставшаяся же в теле человека душа умершего продолжала бы жить по законам «того света», принося живым вред. Остается только удивляться, насколько тонко чувствовал эти оттенки обряда великий русский поэт, коль даже такие, казалось бы, мелкие детали отмечены им в «Сказке о Царе Салтане»: ни царь Салтан, ни ткачиха, ни повариха, ни сватья Баба Бабариха никогда не называют комара – комаром, муху – мухой, а шмеля – шмелем. Когда «с криком ловят комара», то это «распроклятая ты мошка!», когда пытаются поймать муху, то «лови, лови, да дави ее, дави...», когда шмель кусает нос «старой бабушки своей», то мы снова слышим: «лови, да дави его, дави...». Ничто из живого, что может перенести хотя бы кусочек «того света» в наш мир, не может быть названо по имени.

После своих подвигов в мире живых князь Гвидон возвращается на остров Буян, преодолевая морские просторы. Ряженые в русской народной традиции обязательно в Крещение после освящения воды купались в проруби, возвращая «тому свету» душу предка, которому «одалживали» на время Святок свое тело. Сделать это было необходимо, так как с древнейших ведических времен считалось, что кратчайший путь души на небо, в обитель богов и предков, – это погружение в речные или морские воды.

Из древнегреческой мифологии мы знаем, что символом Гипербореи был Лебедь. Образ «звезды во лбу» Пушкин использует, описывая Царевну-лебедь, «сестру» Гвидона. Здесь мы  встречаем архетип птицы, плавающей на вселенских водах. В паре Гвидон – Царевна-Лебедь мы видим образы существ-прародителей с сияющими «звездами во лбу». Это символика просветленных существ.

http://april-journal.com/rubriki/istoriya/96-33-bogatyrya-i-matritsa-mirozdanya

http://changing-world2020.blogspot.com/2012/01/33.html